# JMeter Dynamic Request

Tags: jmeter

I need to test a web service with header-item lines with reading values from csv.

```
<urn:Requisition_BudgetReqExportHeaderDetails_Item>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <urn:item>
           <urn:CompanyCode>
              <urn:UniqueName>?</urn:UniqueName>
           </urn:CompanyCode>
           <urn:ERPRequisitionID>?</urn:ERPRequisitionID>
           <urn:HoldTillDate>?</urn:HoldTillDate>
           <urn:IsServiceRequisition>?</urn:IsServiceRequisition>
           <urn:Name>?</urn:Name>
        </urn:item>
</urn:Requisition_BudgetReqExportHeaderDetails_Item>
```

I can read values from CSV file but this web service is complex and items might be 1 or more than 2.

How can I handle this web service request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like:

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of your request
2. Put the code to generate the XML payload into "Script" area, an example one would look like:

   ```
   def writer = new StringWriter()
   def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer) 

   xml.records() { 
       car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
           country('Australia')
           record(type:'speed', 'Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph')
       }
       car(name:'Royale', make:'Bugatti', year:1931) {
           country('France')
           record(type:'price', 'Most Valuable Car at $15 million')
       }
   }

   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", writer.toString(), "")
   ```

   Amend it to match your requirement
3. When you run your test the JSR223 PreProcessor will generate the request body and set it in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

References:

- `sampler`  - a shorthand to HTTPSamplerProxy class, see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields
- [Groovy - Creating XML](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml) - learn how to create XML data using Groovy language
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) - an introduction to Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use csv values?

Comment: You have `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariarbles](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so if you wanta to use `${foo}` variable it should be something like `def myFooVariable = vars.get('foo')`